# Need help making an autocompleting list from this code, jQuery Mobile

Tags: arrays, listview, jquery-mobile, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

Can someone please help me get a autocompleting list of this code example? I want it to show like my explanation below when you search...

If I start to type for example "Calif" i want it to show like below, and if the letters I type could be highlighted in the list would be nice...

```
[ Los Angeles, California, United States       ]
[ San Diego, California, United States         ]
[ San Jose, California, United States          ]
```

HTML and JavaScript:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>How could I get an autocompleting list instead?</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    /*Countries around the world*/
    var countries = [
        { countryID: 1, name: 'United States' },
        { countryID: 2, name: 'United Kingdom' },
        { countryID: 3, name: 'Germany' },
        { countryID: 4, name: 'Finland' },
        { countryID: 5, name: 'Canada' }
    ]

    /*regions in the countries*/
    var regions = [
        /*regions in United States*/
        { countryID: 1, regionID: 1, name: 'Alaska' },
        { countryID: 1, regionID: 2, name: 'Arizona' },
        { countryID: 1, regionID: 3, name: 'California' },
        { countryID: 1, regionID: 4, name: 'Florida' },
        { countryID: 1, regionID: 5, name: 'Georgia' },
        /*regions in United Kingdom*/
        { countryID: 2, regionID: 6, name: 'England' },
        { countryID: 2, regionID: 7, name: 'Scotland' },
        { countryID: 2, regionID: 8, name: 'Wales' },
        { countryID: 2, regionID: 9, name: 'Northern Ireland' },
        /*regions in Germany*/
        { countryID: 3, regionID: 10, name: 'Bavaria' },
        { countryID: 3, regionID: 11, name: 'Saxony' },
        { countryID: 3, regionID: 12, name: 'Thuringia' },
        { countryID: 3, regionID: 13, name: 'Saarland' },
        /*regions in Finland*/
        { countryID: 4, regionID: 14, name: 'Lappi' },
        { countryID: 4, regionID: 15, name: 'Kainuu' },
        { countryID: 4, regionID: 16, name: 'Pohjois-Savo' },
        /*regions in Canada*/
        { countryID: 5, regionID: 17, name: 'Yukon' },
        { countryID: 5, regionID: 18, name: 'Quebec' },
        { countryID: 5, regionID: 19, name: 'Alberta' },
        { countryID: 5, regionID: 20, name: 'Manitoba' }
    ]

    /*Cities in the regions*/
    var cities = [
        { regionID: 1, cityID: 1, name: 'Sitka', myValueOne: 19.18, myValueTwo: 12.10, myValueThree: 0.16, myValueFour: 0.89 },
        { regionID: 1, cityID: 2, name: 'Juneau', myValueOne: 19.18, myValueTwo: 12.10, myValueThree: 0.12, myValueFour: 0.84 },
        { regionID: 2, cityID: 3, name: 'Phoenix', myValueOne: 19.18, myValueTwo: 12.10, myValueThree: 0.12, myValueFour: 0.80 },
        { regionID: 2, cityID: 4, name: 'Scottsdale', myValueOne: 18.98, myValueTwo: 12.10, myValueThree: 0.165, myValueFour: 0.84 },
        { regionID: 2, cityID: 5, name: 'Yuma', myValueOne: 18.98, myValueTwo: 12.10, myValueThree: 0.215, myValueFour: 1.145 },
        { regionID: 3, cityID: 6, name: 'Los Angeles', myValueOne: 18.65, myValueTwo: 12.10, myValueThree: 0.10, myValueFour: 0.74 },
        { regionID: 3, cityID: 7, name: 'San Diego', myValueOne: 18.65, myValueTwo: 12.10, myValueThree: 0.25, myValueFour: 1.06 },
        { regionID: 3, cityID: 8, name: 'San Jose', myValueOne: 19.91, myValueTwo: 12.10, myValueThree: 0.14, myValueFour: 0.87 },
        { regionID: 4, cityID: 9, name: 'Denver', myValueOne: 19.91, myValueTwo: 12.10, myValueThree: 0.20, myValueFour: 1.17 },
        { regionID: 5, cityID: 10, name: 'Columbus', myValueOne: 19.91, myValueTwo: 12.10, myValueThree: 0.12, myValueFour: 0.78 },
        { regionID: 5, cityID: 11, name: 'Atlanta', myValueOne: 18.98, myValueTwo: 12.10, myValueThree: 0.15, myValueFour: 0.69 },
        { regionID: 6, cityID: 12, name: 'Bath', myValueOne: 19.23, myValueTwo: 12.10, myValueThree: 0.16, myValueFour: 0.94 },
        { regionID: 6, cityID: 13, name: 'Birmingham', myValueOne: 19.23, myValueTwo: 12.10, myValueThree: 0.16, myValueFour: 0.94 },
        { regionID: 6, cityID: 14, name: 'Bradford', myValueOne: 19.23, myValueTwo: 12.10, myValueThree: 0.16, myValueFour: 0.94 },
        { regionID: 7, cityID: 15, name: 'Aberdeen', myValueOne: 19.23, myValueTwo: 12.10, myValueThree: 0.14, myValueFour: 0.96 },
        { regionID: 8, cityID: 16, name: 'Cardiff', myValueOne: 19.85, myValueTwo: 12.10, myValueThree: 0.12, myValueFour: 0.72 },
        { regionID: 8, cityID: 17, name: 'Newport', myValueOne: 19.85, myValueTwo: 12.10, myValueThree: 0.12, myValueFour: 0.72 },
        { regionID: 9, cityID: 18, name: 'Belfast', myValueOne: 19.85, myValueTwo: 12.10, myValueThree: 0.12, myValueFour: 0.72 },
        { regionID: 10, cityID: 19, name: 'Bad Kissingen', myValueOne: 19.23, myValueTwo: 12.10, myValueThree: 0.14, myValueFour: 0.96 },
        { regionID: 11, cityID: 20, name: 'Bad Lausick', myValueOne: 19.85, myValueTwo: 12.10, myValueThree: 0.12, myValueFour: 0.72 },
        { regionID: 12, cityID: 21, name: 'Bad Langensaiza', myValueOne: 19.85, myValueTwo: 12.10, myValueThree: 0.12, myValueFour: 0.72 },
        { regionID: 13, cityID: 22, name: 'Blieskastel', myValueOne: 19.85, myValueTwo: 12.10, myValueThree: 0.12, myValueFour: 0.72 },
        { regionID: 13, cityID: 23, name: 'Dillingen', myValueOne: 19.23, myValueTwo: 12.10, myValueThree: 0.14, myValueFour: 0.96 },
        { regionID: 14, cityID: 24, name: 'Rovaniemi', myValueOne: 19.85, myValueTwo: 12.10, myValueThree: 0.12, myValueFour: 0.72 },
        { regionID: 15, cityID: 25, name: 'Kajaani', myValueOne: 19.85, myValueTwo: 12.10, myValueThree: 0.12, myValueFour: 0.72 },
        { regionID: 16, cityID: 26, name: 'Kuopio', myValueOne: 19.85, myValueTwo: 12.10, myValueThree: 0.12, myValueFour: 0.72 },
        { regionID: 17, cityID: 27, name: 'Whitehorse', myValueOne: 19.85, myValueTwo: 12.10, myValueThree: 0.12, myValueFour: 0.72 },
        { regionID: 18, cityID: 28, name: 'Quebec City', myValueOne: 19.85, myValueTwo: 12.10, myValueThree: 0.12, myValueFour: 0.72 },
        { regionID: 19, cityID: 29, name: 'Edmonton', myValueOne: 19.85, myValueTwo: 12.10, myValueThree: 0.12, myValueFour: 0.72 },
        { regionID: 20, cityID: 30, name: 'Winnipeg', myValueOne: 19.85, myValueTwo: 12.10, myValueThree: 0.12, myValueFour: 0.72 }
    ]

    // returns array of elements whose 'prop' property is 'value'
    function filterByProperty(arr, prop, value) {
        return $.grep(arr, function (item) { return item[prop] == value });
    }
    // populates select list from array of items given as objects: { name: 'text', value: 'value' }
    function populateSelect(el, items) {
        el.options.length = 0;
        if (items.length > 0)
            el.options[0] = new Option('Select one...', '');
        $.each(items, function () {
            el.options[el.options.length] = new Option(this.name, this.value);
        });
    }
    // initialization
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // populating 1st select list
        populateSelect($('#chooseCountry').get(0), $.map(countries, function (type) { return { name: type.name, value: type.countryID } }));
        // populating 2nd select list
        $('#chooseCountry').bind('change', function () {
            var kommunerna = filterByProperty(regions, 'countryID', this.value);
            populateSelect($('#chooseRegion').get(0), $.map(kommunerna, function (make) { return { name: make.name, value: make.regionID } }));
            $('#chooseRegion').trigger('change');
        });
        // populating 3nd select list
        $('#chooseRegion').bind('change', function () {
            var forsamlingarna = filterByProperty(cities, 'regionID', this.value);
            populateSelect($('#chooseCity').get(0), $.map(forsamlingarna, function (model) { return { name: model.name, value: model.cityID } }));


            // check if you are a member of blablabla
            if ($("#memberCheck").is(':checked'))
                $('#chooseCity').bind('change', function () {
                    var valueForMe = filterByProperty(cities, 'cityID', this.value);
                    $.map(valueForMe, function (skatt) { $("#textForMyValue").html((skatt.myValueOne + skatt.myValueTwo + skatt.myValueThree + skatt.myValueFour).toFixed(3) + "%") });
                });
            else
                $('#chooseCity').bind('change', function () {
                    var valueForMe = filterByProperty(cities, 'cityID', this.value);
                    $.map(valueForMe, function (skatt) { $("#textForMyValue").html((skatt.myValueOne + skatt.myValueTwo + skatt.myValueThree).toFixed(3) + "%") });
                });
        });
        $('#memberCheck').click(function () {

            $("#textForMyValue").empty();
            $("select#chooseCity").val('').attr('selected', true);


            if ($("#memberCheck").is(':checked'))
                $('#chooseCity').bind('change', function () {
                    var valueForMe = filterByProperty(cities, 'cityID', this.value);
                    $.map(valueForMe, function (skatt) { $("#textForMyValue").html((skatt.myValueOne + skatt.myValueTwo + skatt.myValueThree + skatt.myValueFour).toFixed(3) + "%") });
                });
            else
                $('#chooseCity').bind('change', function () {
                    var valueForMe = filterByProperty(cities, 'cityID', this.value);
                    $.map(valueForMe, function (skatt) { $("#textForMyValue").html((skatt.myValueOne + skatt.myValueTwo + skatt.myValueThree).toFixed(3) + "%") });
                });
        });



    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form method="get">
    <div id="selection">
        <select id="chooseCountry" name="country_id"></select>
        <select id="chooseRegion" name="region_id"></select>
        <select id="chooseCity" name="city_id"></select>          
    </div>

    <input type="checkbox" id="memberCheck" /> Are you a member of blablalbla?
    <div id="textDiv">Your value is: <div id="textForMyValue"></div></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a the [Autocomplete](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0-rc.1/docs/demos/widgets/autocomplete/) from jquery-mobile. You can create the content by appending it to the autocomplete as `li` elment and then make a refresh for the list. Here is an example.

HTML:

JS:

```
var cities = [{
    regionID: 1,
    cityID: 1,
    name: 'Sitka',
    myValueOne: 19.18,
    myValueTwo: 12.10,
    myValueThree: 0.16,
    myValueFour: 0.89
} ...];
var listView = $("[data-role='listview']");

$(cities).each(function () {
    var test = "[" + this.regionID + " " + this.cityID + " " + this.name + "]";
    listView.append('<li data-filtertext="' + test + '"><a href="#">' + test + '</a></li>');
});
listView.listview('refresh');
```

Fiddler example: http://jsfiddle.net/D64sh/

In the `data-filtertext` are the values you can search, in the a element is the text wich is displayed to the suer.

It's up to you to merge your three data objects into one.